# Focusing div elements with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to focus div (or any other elements) using the `focus()` method?

I've set a tabIndex to a div element:

```
<div ref="dropdown" tabIndex="1"></div>
```

And I can see it gets focused when I click on it, however, I'm trying to dynamically focus the element like this:

```
setActive(state) {
  ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.dropdown).focus();
}
```

Or like this:

```
this.refs.dropdown.focus();
```

But the component doesn't get focus when the event is triggered. How can I do this? Is there any other (not input) element I can use for this?

EDIT:

Well, It seems this it actually possible to do: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/54201/

But it is not working for me, this is my full code:

```
class ColorPicker extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      active: false,
      value: ""
    };
  }

  selectItem(color) {
    this.setState({ value: color, active: false });
  }

  setActive(state) {
    this.setState({ active: state });
    this.refs.dropdown.focus();
  }

  render() {
    const { colors, styles, inputName } = this.props;

    const pickerClasses = classNames('colorpicker-dropdown', { 'active': this.state.active });

    const colorFields = colors.map((color, index) => {
      const colorClasses = classNames('colorpicker-item', [`colorpicker-item-${color}`]);

      return (
        <div onClick={() => { this.selectItem(color) }} key={index} className="colorpicker-item-container">
          <div className={colorClasses}></div>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="colorpicker">
        <input type="text" className={styles} name={inputName} ref="component" value={this.state.value} onFocus={() => { this.setActive(true) }} />
        <div onBlur={() => this.setActive(false) } onFocus={() => console.log('focus')} tabIndex="1" ref="dropdown" className={pickerClasses}>
          {colorFields}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you assigning the ref?

Comment: sorry, updated, I'm assigning the ref to the same div element with the tabIndex

Comment: I tried this in a fiddle and it works https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/54201/, but not working in my code, I updated to question to include it

Comment: This article helps me a lot: https://www.tuomokankaanpaa.com/blog/how-to-focus-element-in-react

Answer (score 30, accepted):

React redraws the component every time you set the state, meaning that the component loses focus. In this kind of instances it is convenient to use the `componentDidUpdate` or `componentDidMount` methods if you want to focus the element based on a prop, or state element.

Keep in mind that as per React Lifecycle documentation, `componentDidMount` will only happen after rendering the component for the first time on the screen, and in this call `componentDidUpdate` will not occur, then for each new `setState`, `forceUpdate` call or the component receiving new props the `componentDidUpdate` call will occur.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.focusDiv();
},
componentDidUpdate() {
  if(this.state.active)
    this.focusDiv();
},
focusDiv() {
  ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.theDiv).focus();
}
```

Here is a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vankovilija/69z2wepo/54202/) you can play around with.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks man! `componentDidUpdate` did the trick

Comment: Would it be possible to update the JS fiddle to work 5 years later (anyone)? It's just the top answer for this question and it'd be nice to have the working example. I did try myself but guess I'm not quite adept enough, thank you

Answer (score 9):

This is the problem:

```
this.setState({ active: state });
this.refs.component.focus();
```

Set state is rerendering your component and the call is asynchronous, so you *are* focusing, it's just immediately rerendering after it focuses and you lose focus. Try using the `setState` callback

```
this.setState({ active: state }, () => {
   this.refs.component.focus();
});
```

Comment: Hmm, no, even if I don't call setState the element isn't getting focus :(

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is get a reference to the element you want to programmatically set the focus on, and remember to set a tabIndex on it if it's by default  unfocusable.

Example using function components:

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';

const MyFC = () => {
  const containerWrapperRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={containerWrapperRef} tabIndex={-1}>
        I get focus when button is clicked
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => containerWrapperRef.current?.focus()}>Focus</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default MyFC;
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to answer but the reason why your event handler is not working is probably because you are not binding your functions and so 'this' used inside the function would be undefined when you pass it as eg: "this.selectItem(color)"

In the constructor do:

```
this.selectItem = this.selectItem.bind(this)

this.setActive = this.setActive.bind(this)
```

Comment: Note that I was wrapping the setActive function call with an arrow function: `onFocus={() => { this.setActive(true) }}`, doing that gives you the correct context, so using `.bind(this)` won't change the way the snippet works

Answer (score 0):

If somehow we don't have access to ref (Maybe using some third-party library or having our own custom component) then in order to do so in react we can make use of vanilla JS like so

```
;(document.getElementsByClassName('sort-dropdown-span-button')[0] as HTMLDivElement).focus()
```

**Note:** But that particular div must have class say **sort-dropdown-span-button** (like in above example) and **tabIndex=0**

Answer (score -2):

This worked in my case

```
render: function(){

  if(this.props.edit){
    setTimeout(()=>{ this.divElement.focus() },0)
  }

    return <div ref={ divElement => this.divElement = divElement}
                contentEditable={props.edit}/>
}
```