# Is it possible to apply focus to an input element inside one of my React components without assigning a ref to the input tag directly?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, focus, html-input

I am losing focus of my text input boxes when the component re-renders. I can re-apply the focus to an `<input>` element by adding a ref (something like the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174887/focusing-div-elements-with-react)), but what can I do if I don't have access to the `<input>` element because it is inside a custom component. I can obviously edit the component or forgo using it altogether, but I'm wondering if there is another way to re-apply focus on my textbox.

I have a custom component called `<TextInput>`. I can add a ref to this component, but it ends up on the outer `<div>` of this component, and not on the `<input>` tag contained within my `<TextInput>` element.

Please let me know if there is any way to apply the ref to the inner `<input>` element without modifying my component, or if I could utilize a different strategy for re-applying focus after my component re-renders.

Please let me know if I am being unclear or if you require additional information. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: What about setting autoFocus to your element e.g. < input autoFocus /> ?

Comment: Have you read the whole section at https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html Maybe the `inputRef` case can be applied to your case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the focus is lost when the `input` element is re-rendered (because an ancestor of it got re-rendered).
If that's the case then you can do something like:

```
<input ref={ (el) => el.focus() } />
```

Sometimes this works better with a short delay:

```
<input ref={ (el) => setTimeout(() => el.focus(), 100) } />
```