# React - set accessibility focus to an element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an h1 element within a react template as follows:

```
<section className={containerClasses}>
    { headline && <h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: headline }} />}
</section>
```

This component is part of a page component that slides down informing the user of the results from their last action which was clicking a button. I need to be able to set the focus on h1 element for accessibility requirements and cannot figure out how to do this.

What I have tried:

I have added a ref to the component and attempted to see if there was any focus method available but there isn't

```
 <section className={containerClasses}>
        { headline && <h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: headline }} ref={this.focusElement} />}
 </section>
```

And attempting to access the element by:

```
this.focusElement.current.focus()
```

Any assist would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `h1` tags, and others like them, is that they are not inherently focusable. However, by adding a `tabindex` to the tag, you should be able to add focus to the element programmatically:

- https://davidwalsh.name/tabindex-focus
- https://css-tricks.com/focus-styles-non-interactive-elements/

So, you can try

```
<h1 tabindex="-1" .../>
```

Comment: I tried that. The component opens and the voice over reads the proper text but the focus remains on the initial button that was clicked.

Comment: Where are you calling `this.focusElement.current.focus()`?

Comment: Also, do you have `this.focusElement = React.createRef()` within the constructor of that component?

Comment: Yes I did. I also manually looked in the object and there is no focus method, not even on the prototype.

Comment: I use this pen to play around with React questions. I'm replicating your question and it seems to work. Have you tried styling the `:focus` state of your `h1` tag? https://codepen.io/wesleylhandy/pen/qxdVpE

Comment: Are you calling `setState` somewhere than could be affecting focus? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174887/focusing-div-elements-with-react

Comment: Its working now. I added tabIndex={-1} instead of tabindex="-1". Then the call to this.focusElement.current.focus() worked.

Comment: Your answer works as well. Im actually not sure why this wasn't working before. Anyways Im awarding the answer to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `tabIndex` property AND call `this.focusElement.current.focus()`.

> A tabindex="-1" value removes the element from the default navigation flow and also allows it to receive programmatic focus. This means focus can be set to it from a link, or with scripting. This may be useful for elements that should not be navigated to, but need to have focus set to them [(source)](https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex#negative-one).

If you want the user to be able to navigate to your `h1` element you should instead set the value to 0 which will include the element in default navigation order.

> A value of 0 indicates that the element should be placed in the default navigation order. This allows elements that are not natively focusable (such as `<div>`, `<span>`, `<p>`, and `<a>` with no href) to receive keyboard focus. Links and form controls are best for almost all interactive elements, but tabindex="0" allows other elements to be focusable and able to trigger interaction [(source)](https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex#zero).