# Need to put focus on div in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a text which was earlier wrapped in an H1 tag. I need to focus on that text once my page is loaded. I wrapped it in a div for my convenience.

```
render() {
    const { translate, billing: { primaryContactSelection = true } } = this.props;
    return (
      <div {...resolve(BillingStyles, 'billingContainer')}>
        <div id="mainHeader"><h1 {...resolve(BillingStyles, 'mainHeader')}>
          {translate('PanelBillingHeadingText')}
        </h1> </div>
        <div {...resolve(BillingStyles, 'billingInfoContainer')}>
         ......
         ......
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried the below code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Component Did Mount .............');
    document.getElementById('#mainHeader').focus();
  }
```

But it is not focusing on the div.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Focusing div elements with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174887/focusing-div-elements-with-react)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to focus on a <div> using JavaScript focus() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656467/is-it-possible-to-focus-on-a-div-using-javascript-focus-function)

Comment: I have tried these , but it is not working fro me

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by focus on div? divs are not focusable

Comment: I have a text which was earlier wrapped in h1 tag , i need to focus on that text once my page is loaded . I wrapped in div for my convinience. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First `div` elements are not focusable by default so you need to give it a [tabIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex):

```
render() {
    const { translate, billing: { primaryContactSelection = true } } = this.props;
    return (
      <div {...resolve(BillingStyles, 'billingContainer')}>
        <div tabIndex="0" id="mainHeader"><h1 {...resolve(BillingStyles, 'mainHeader')}>
          {translate('PanelBillingHeadingText')}
        </h1> </div>
        <div {...resolve(BillingStyles, 'billingInfoContainer')}>
         ......
         ......
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Next make sure you don't include the hashtag when calling getElementById, so it should be :

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Component Did Mount .............');
    document.getElementById('mainHeader').focus();
  }
```

And that should work from there.

Comment: This is still helpful in 2022 :) I was trying to focus a div using a react `ref.current.focus()` call and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working. Adding the tabIndex did the trick!

Comment: still working. saved my couple of hours. Thanks @Dmitriy

Answer (score 1):

When you use getElementById function you don't need `#` sign inside braces.