# I want to give style to a div element like on Input

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

On input html element I can change :hover, :focus styles. I want to do the same thing for a div but it didn't work.
I am using React.js, I am able to change the background color with condition:

```
<div style={{backgroundColor: isClicked ? 'yellow' : null }}>
```

in this scenario, after I click background is yellow, but it stays yellow even if I click somewhere other than this div element.

Is there a way to change the backgroundColor only on focusing a div element?

---

I am able to change the style with tabindex as @jjroley answered.

Facing another problem now.

The structure of my code is like this:

```
<div className={styles['Editor-container']} tabIndex={1}>
      <Editor
        options={{ readOnly: !canEditEditor }}
        height="20vh"
        defaultLanguage="json"
        defaultValue={formatJSON(JSON.stringify(documentInfo))}
        onChange={(value, event) => handleChange(value, event)}
        onValidate={handleValidation}
      />
    </div>
```

When I click Editor it doesn't focus. Is there a way to solve this too? Thank you.

Comment: If you want to focus the div, try giving it a tabindex. Also, use `"none"` instead of `null` when setting the background color

Comment: Hey thank you. I gave tabindex but still not working

Comment: This may answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174887/focusing-div-elements-with-react

Comment: I am able to change the backgroundcolor now, but facing another problem. Can you please check the updated question again? Maybe you can help me with this, as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`:hover` for a pure css solution (but no click). or a html check box and css style. No Java-script is needed.

Comment: I need to change background color after I focus on the Div. :hover is working

Comment: When you say focus, do you mean click/select?

Comment: Yes. Like on Input element. I can change focus style when I click input, so I want to do the same thing on Div element.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Have you tried a check box, plus css?